# Facebook SDK- Developers accounts can't login

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I've got a strange problem. People with a certain type of developer account cannot log in- including me (the maker of the app).

Non-developer facebook accounts can login.

The error says "Invalid Scopes: friends_about_me" etc. I've attached a screenshot below.

I've searched for hours- but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: add your code here. @Ycon

Comment: Code from where? I cannot get access to our app's files

Comment: check your code in permission, i thing this "friends_about_me"  is wrong. @Ycon

Comment: I have a screenshot of the error? What do you mean- it says that "friends_about_me" is the error

Comment: yes this permission is remove from new version of Facebook SDK.

Comment: So the only way to fix this is to removed the version of the Facebook SDK on my app (and thus have to update my app)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86740/discussion-between-ycon-and-dharmesh-dhorajiya).

Answer (score 2):

There is no permissions like friends_about_me

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4

May you are looking for :

> **user_about_me**
>
> Provides access to a person's personal description (the 'About Me'
>   section on their Profile) through the bio property on the User object.
>
> This permission does not give access to a person's public profile
>   data. A person's name, profile picture, locale, age range and gender
>   are included by default with the public_profile permission.

Check the change log  : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> All friends_* permissions have been removed. They include:
>
> friends_about_me
>   friends_actions.books
>   friends_actions.fitness
>   friends_actions.music
>   and many more...

Comment: Is the only way to fix this update the Facebook SDK in the app itself?

Comment: @Ycon You have to use the SDK 4.4 Which is latest version. add it to your project and change your permissions in your code (Xcode Project). Hope you are getting.